# Android Google Maps: which API used to search places nearby your current location?

Tags: android

On Android Google Maps, which API is used to search restaurant, pubs, ATM etc. nearby the user's current location ?
Is that Google API available for public use? If it's available, please provide its link and how to use it .

Comment: Its Google places api and for that you would need to get and places api key...

Answer (score 0):

hi you can get all the information that you need related to Places API in this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/)

And for the example for parsing json data have look at this [Link](http://activecodeline.net/simple-android-json-parsing-example-with-output-into-listactivity)

Hope this could help you...